# Error: code is JavaScript document.getElementById('splash').style.display = 'none'

Tags: javascript

is JavaScript code in google
Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

```
document.getElementById('splash').style.display = 'none'
```

Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

```
                document.getElementById('splash').style.display = 'none'
        console.log("Already shown");
      }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFi73.jpg)It shows an error in this code, the code

Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

```
document.getElementById('splash').style.display = 'none'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jh3t.jpg)

Comment: The error is telling you: at the point the script is running that line of code the element you've specified in the selector cannot be found in the DOM.

Comment: The of is correct? The script is executing before the DOM?

Comment: Does your HTML have an element with `id="splash"`...?  That's the only way I really see this happening.

Answer (score 0):

If your element does truly exist, then the problem is most likely that you are referencing your js file in a `<script>` tag in the body of your html *before* the element itself. You need to make sure that the script tag is placed at the complete bottom of the `<body>` tag after the element you have defined. Another way is to put the script tag in the html head tag and add a simple property of `defer="true"`. Lastly, if you do not want to do that, simply in your js just do a `window.onload = () => { //write all your code here }` and with that function when you console.log() the element, it would have loaded.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("splash");
elem.style.display= 'none';
```

does your element have class name?